# How to Install cURL on PHP5 on a remote Server

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to install cURL on a remote server through my Mac, but for some reason I am unable to do so.

Here are the steps I followed:-

1. ssh'ed the remote server
2. wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.14.0.tar.gz
3. zcat curl-7.14.0.tar.gz | tar xvf -
4. cd curl-7.14.0/
5. make (gave me the error:- (as followed))

   ```
   ./configure
   checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
   checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
   checking for ar... ar
   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
   checking for gawk... gawk
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
   checking curl version... 7.14.0
   checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking for style of include used by make... GNU
   checking for gcc... no
   checking for cc... no
   checking for cc... no
   checking for cl... no
   configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
   See `config.log' for more details.
   make: *** [all] Error 1
   ```
6. make install (gave me the error)

   ```
   make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
   ```

Could you guys assist me in this? I just have to install cURL on my server. I also tried running `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` but it gave me error that apt-get doesn't exist.

Comment: What linux distro is this? Have you tried `sudo yum install php5-curl`?

Comment: tried, it says sudo: yum: command not found. The distro is :- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 1

Comment: Ouch, sounds like a pretty barebones linux install. I would start by just installing a package manager...

Comment: Thanks Matt, could you elaborate a little that how could I install a package manager?

Comment: Actually it looks like SUSE uses zypper. Try `zypper info php5-curl` http://en.opensuse.org/images/3/30/Zypper-cheat-sheet-2.pdf

Comment: Ok, it went well. Following is what it showed:- Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...  Is it installed?


Information for package php5-curl:

Repository: SP1
Name: php5-curl
Version: 5.2.14-0.7.24.1
Arch: x86_64
Vendor: SUSE LINUX Products GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany
Support Level: unknown
Installed: No
Status: not installed
Installed Size: 62.0 KiB
Summary: PHP5 Extension Module
Description: 
PHP interface to libcurl that allows you to connect to and communicate
with servers of many different types, using protocols of many different
types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on our convo and the fact that you are using SUSE, it looks like you can simply use Zypper (package manager) to install it. Try the following command:

```
zypper install php5-curl
```

Then, restart apache.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this is what I did.

```
logged in with ssh

sudo zypper in curl

sudo /sbin/yast -i curl

zypper in php5-curl

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Thanks a lot Matthew.